# Blazor Web Assembly WASM Authentikation PostAsJsonAsync Bad Request

Tags: blazor-webassembly

maybe someone can help me out on this one..... why in var "result" i have Status Code: Bad Request????

```
public class PublicClient
    {
        public HttpClient Client { get; }

        public PublicClient(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            Client = httpClient;
        }

public async Task<TEntity> Insert<TEntity>(TEntity entity, string controllerName) where TEntity : class
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await Client.PostAsJsonAsync(controllerName, entity);
                result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIEntityResponse<TEntity>>
                    (responseBody);
                return response.Data;
                if (response.Success)
                    return response.Data;
                else
                    return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

in Program.cs Client:

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BlazorApp.PublicServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<PublicClient>(client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("BlazorApp.PublicServerAPI"));
```

At first there was a problem with AccessTokenNotAvailableException I created another client, for unauthorized users. Now this error appeared. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You're successfully calling the endpoint, but it doesn't like what you're trying to post to it. Try debugging or logging out the result of "await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()" and the endpoint will probably tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by canceling the field to be mandatory, put a question mark for example:

public string? Name { get; set}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).